# Strapi Responsive UI

Tags: strapi

I'm looking at Strapi alpha 3.x and love the simplicity and speed, and the fact that it runs on Node.

Is there any plan to make the UI responsive to support tablets and mobile phones?

Answer (score 3):

I work at Strapi and currently the admin is not responsive because it's mostly used on desktop. In the future we will consider (when we have time) to make it responsive but it's not our main concern at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Right now it's being considered: https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/c/20-administration-responsive 
It's not the most important feature requested, but you can vote to make it happen!